# AWS Dynamodb: validation error when calling put_item method

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

The table in dynamodb has 2 columns: timeStamp(string) and tableName(string)
when trying to insert datetime as string, it fails with this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Item.timeStamp, value: 2022-03-17 16:46:46.510210, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

here is the code snippet:

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime as dt

def put_data(timeStamp, tableName):
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    
    
    #data = json.loads(json.dumps({"timeStamp":timeStamp ,"tableName":tableName}))
    
    #print(data)
    
    response = dynamodb.put_item(TableName='dev-data-migration-state', Item= {"timeStamp":timeStamp ,"tableName":tableName})
    
    print(response)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    put_data(json.loads(json.dumps(str(dt.now()))), 'orders')
```

i have tried just doing str(dt.now) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I'm using the client-API, so I needed to put the data in the DynamoDB-JSON format with the data type:

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime as dt

def put_data(timeStamp, tableName):
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    response = dynamodb.put_item(TableName='dev-data-migration-state', 
    Item= {
        "timeStamp":{'S': timeStamp},
        "tableName":{'S': tableName}
    }
    )
    
    print(response)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    put_data(str(dt.now()), 'orders')
```